# Solr highlighted search

Tags: solr, nutch

I am using SOLR with Nutch

I am using highlighted search in SOLR it works fine for me

But it returns only one field that we give for highlighting

If I give two fields like hl.fl = title,content then for some records title is not coming

In schema.xml title field looks like

```
<field name="title" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>
```

How can i get extra fields in highlighted search result.

I need to display highlighted search results with all fields i have...

Comment: are you using `h.fl` or `hl.fl`? Is your title field stored inside your schema.xml?

Comment: I am using hl.fl and title field is in my schema.xml actually when i gave two fields in hl.fl=title,content then the search word like "disease" if not appears in title then it not displayed title

Comment: How does your title field look like in the schema.xml?

Comment: it looks like this : <field name="title" type="text" stored="true" indexed="true"/>

Comment: You can add it to your question. WHile you're at it, how does the text fieldType look like?

Comment: I have edit the question if thats what you want ...

Comment: Well, it isnt' what I want, it's what the people here like: understand what you're asking and try to help knowing as many details as possible. BTW: the text fieldType is still missing.

Comment: ohh i got your point, i will next time make sure to provide as much details as possible. besides i have provided type attribute which is text and no other fieldType define in my schema.xml for title field...

Comment: type="text" means that you have a fieldType with name text in your schema.xml, on which you can configure Analyzers, Filters etc. Can you please post that fragment?

Answer (score 1):

If "for some records title is not coming" that suggests that `title` doesn't match your query in those circumstances. Highlighting will only return snippets from fields that actually contain matches. What I would suggest is the following:

1. Run your query with `hl.fragsize = 0`. That will return the entire
   contents of the field.
2. If you don't have a title match in the highlighting structure,
   display the title returned from the search w/o highlighting.
3. If do do have a title match in highlighting, display that in place
   of the title.

Hope this helps.